# Change a button's content in a style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
        <Button>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Content"
                            Value="No mouse over" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <CheckBox Content="Mouse is over" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, I get a run-time XamlParseException with a message of:

> Cannot add content of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox' to
>   an object of type 'System.Object'. 
>   Error at object
>   'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox

I'm actually trying to draw different icons for the button's content depending on external conditions. So I'm actually trying to use a DataTrigger, but the example above simplifies the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 39):

The actual error is occurring because Visuals can not be directly set as a Setter value.
You can get the behavior you are looking for though, by setting the ContentTemplate using a DataTemplate, or by creating your content as a resource, either specific to the button or located elsewhere.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Resources>
        <CheckBox x:Key="Local_MouseOverContent" Content="Mouse is over" />
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="No mouse over" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content"
                            Value="{StaticResource Local_MouseOverContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>

<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="No mouse over" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="Button">
                                <CheckBox Content="Mouse is over" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 6):

REMARK! Exactly your example works in **.NET Framework 4** without any Changes !!!!

```
  <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Content"
                        Value="No mouse over" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <CheckBox Content="Mouse is over" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: This really works, ty! It stops working, when the `Button.Content` property is set with an attribute though. i.e. `<Button Content="initial content" Style="{StaticResource StyleChangeContentOnMouseOver}" />` will only display `"initial content"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a generic style to be used by buttons all around your app, you will get visual tree conflicts using the approach where the image is a resource. So the template is your only choice in that case.

Answer (score -1):

### **WARNING:** This may not be the best or correct way to do it. Make sure you read the other answers on this page as well.

Pretty sure you'd want to use a control template in this sort of situation. Something like:

```
<style>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Img="something.jpg" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</style>
```

And add a control template in the trigger for the on-hover.

Here's a good [link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Templates.html)

Comment: This isn't something that works. A ControlTemplate is and should be used to modify the visual structure and behavior of a control, not it's content. Also, the ContentProperty can't even render a ControlTemplate unless you also set up a ContentTemplate for it.

Comment: As moore said, this doesn't work. You need to set the ContentTemplate property to a DataTemplate.

Comment: Sorry, I voted you down but now SO won't let me take it back. I've read the article you pointed to and it does seem strangely that ControlTemplate can be set as the content of a control based on that article. Plus you stated very clearly that this may not be the optimal solution.

Comment: @jpierson the article is fine, but the solution is really not optimal. I have voted +1 for the sake of it; It's a different solution after all, but it does works.