# Accessing class properties in xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I've currently created the class below.  For some reason though I can't access the properties I've created through my xaml style.

```
Public Class Ribbon : Inherits Button
    Private mpopDropdown As Popup

    Public Property Dropdown() As Popup
        Get
            Return mpopDropdown
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Popup)
            mpopDropdown = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ...

End Class


<Style TargetType="{x:Type s:Ribbon}">
    <Setter Property="Ribbon.Dropdown">
```

At this point there is an "Invalid PropertyDescriptor value" error.

What can I do to make this property accessible?

**EDIT:**  I have tried creating a `DependencyProperty` as well, as I've read this could solve my problem, but it didn't seem to.

**EDIT 2:**  I've tried

```
Public Shared Readonly DropdownProperty as DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register("Dropdown",GetType(Popup),GetType(Ribbon), _
    New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(False))
```

and

```
Public Shared Readonly DropdownProperty as DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register("Dropdown",GetType(Popup),GetType(Ribbon), _
    New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(True))
```

but they don't seem to expose the property either.  I've also tagged the property as `<Bindable(True)>` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a separate Popup style and setting the style of my object in the class's code and setting the Popup's `PlacementTarget = Me`.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency properties should fix your problem indeed. And don't forget about namespace i.e.  `<Setter Property="s:Ribbon.Dropdown">` although you don't have to specify class owner for properties in setter, if you specified `TargetType`. That means you could write `<Setter Property="Dropdown">`

PS: You may also run into another problem with setting visuals through styles. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050737/wpf-change-a-buttons-content-in-a-style/1050970#1050970). But that's another story...