# Setting Button's Content to <Image> via Styles

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button, styles

Can't get this to work:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Button.Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="D:\Temp\dictionary16.png"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

This code throws the following exception (pointing to the second button):

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

Comment: You can also use attached properties to make Image button

Comment: Yes but as if I see this correctly I would have to use some C#-Code, if possible I want some pure-wpf/xaml-soloution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The style creates one instance of the `Image`, you cannot use it in two places like this. You can create the image as a separate resource with [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)`= false` and reference it in the style then a new one will be created in every place the style is used.

---

e.g.

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="img" x:Shared="false" Source="D:\Temp\dictionary16.png" />
        <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource img}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code in your answer?
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Image Source="D:\Temp\dictionary16.png" x:Key="TestImage" x:Shared="true"/>
       </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource TestImage}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
This is the way I understood it, but it ends in the same exception

Comment: Added an example which worked for me. (I used a different Image.Source of course)

Comment: Crazy Sh***... I tested your soloution in every way it could be interpreded and I was sure in one of this I had exactly the same code you posted now but it didn't work. But then just copied yor posted code and BAAAAM it worked. Thanks man...

Comment: -1: This is not the correct way of handling this in WPF. Tried it in my project and it did not work, maybe because the code was in an external DLL. You should instead set the content via ContentTemplate, which will ensure that a new image is created for each button.

Comment: @reSPAWNed: There is no "correct" way. If you did not get this to work it is your own fault. Also in many cases where controls do not allow extensive templating this is *the only way* to make it work.

Comment: @H.B.: Point taken. There are many solutions to a problem, however I think the solution of using ContentTemplate is a better or more WPF-ish way of solving the problem. All I could establish is that your solution did not work in my case, which might be due to the fact that the code lies in a UserControl located in a separate DLL.

Comment: @reSPAWNed: Well, i already conceded that the templating solution is preferable in this case in my comment on Reini's answer, i just think your down-vote may be unwarranted...

Answer (score 11):

Already yesterday i found a user with a similar problem: [WPF - Change a button's content in a style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050737/wpf-change-a-buttons-content-in-a-style)

This post got me to this soloution (couldn't post it because of 8 hour limit of stackoverflow -.-)

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{mcWPF:LangRes imgSettings16, Bitmap}" Height="14"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Don't know weather this is more clean/dirty/better than H.B.'s soloution

Comment: That is cleaner, i would recommend the use of template properties where possible.

Comment: +1: The marked answer did not work in my scenario, but this did... Much cleaner and better solution.