# How to switch between views using DataTemplate + Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a requirement where a where user can switch to view hierarchical data either as tree or as a text in datagrid or as FlowChart.

The user can do this by clicking a Toggle Button which say: Switch Mode. I want to do all this in such a way that it can be handled within the View only as ViewModel in all the three cases is the same.

How do I apply View to my ViewModel based on Trigger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the state of which view to show is saved in some enum property you could use a [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) and [`DataTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DataTrigger.aspx) for example:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewMode}" Value="TreeMode">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <uc:TreeModeView />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewMode}" Value="GridMode">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <uc:GridModeView />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

(As the style is only used in one place, by setting it directly as `ContentControl.Style` this will work, if you want to use it in more than one place you should set the `ContentTemplate` instead, because otherwise there will only be one view instance shared by all controls with the style which is not allowed by WPF (of course `Content` needs to be set to *something* for the template to be applied))

You could also bind directly to `IsChecked` of the `ToggleButton` using [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) of course. The relevant values would then be `True`, `False` and `{x:Null}`.

Comment: I love this answer but it really does show how verbose WPF can be sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

H.B.'s answer is good, but there are scenarios where it's not quite so good.

If constructing the views (and their underlying view models) is expensive, then toggling the `Content` property will pay this expense every time the user changes the view.

In some scenarios, it makes sense to create both views in the same container (e.g. a `Grid`), and toggle their `Visibility` instead.  If you use lazy evaluation in your view models, the expensive operations won't be conducted until the view becomes visible, and - importantly - they'll only be conducted the *first* time the view becomes visible.  Once both views have been displayed, the user can toggle back and forth between views without reconstructing the underlying view models.

**Edit:**

I stand corrected, sort of:  H.B.'s answer is not as good as it looked .

You can't use a style to set the `Content` property of a `ContentControl` to a `UIElement`.  See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/01/05/styling-the-content-of-a-contentcontrol.aspx) for full details, but the long and short of it is that if you use H.B.'s approach, you'll get a runtime error.

You can set the `ContentTemplate` property, instead, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewMode}"
                        Value="TreeMode">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <uc:TreeModeView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewMode}"
                        Value="GridMode">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <uc:GridModeView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Actually that is not the case, unlike datatemplates Setters only create one instance of those objects, you can test this by just using a TextBox as content and changing its text, then cycle through the views, it will still be there. If this was not the case there would not be problems such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6356810/546730).

Comment: That's interesting.  While I was trying to construct a demo to determine if it's true in this case, I discovered that a consequence of what you're describing is that the approach in your answer actually doesn't work at all.  See my edit.

Comment: You might have misunderstood the problem here, the key sentence is: *"This throws an exception because the value of Setter.Value is shared and objects that inherit from UIElement cannot have more than one parent."* So if this style is never used for more than one ContentControl (which can be ensured by setting it directly and not providing it as a resource) this is no problem at all. (I also have used this method in one of applications before and it works just fine).

Comment: Actually you can even make this work for multiple style targets, you just need to define the Style as a resource with [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) set to `false`, try it. (Like, how cool is that?)

Comment: Well, I tested your code - I copied it into a project and created `TreeViewMode` and `GridModeView` controls, and just as the blog post I linked to indicates, it crashes.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Quite possibly, but i cannot tell you what without any code (or exception messages for that matter). I just tested this again copying the code in my answer and it worked just as i expected. If you post your code somewhere or upload the whole project i could have a look at it if you want.

Comment: Hey, recently i stumbled upon another article regarding this, turns out you could not set the `Content` to an UI element until .NET 4. So i'll assume you were using 3.5 when you tested this.