# Selecting Controls based on Enum

Tags: .net, wpf

I have an enumeration which basically lists the type of control to be displayed and I want to, based on the value of this enum in my ViewModel, display the appropriate control.

Something like this:

```
public enum ControlType
{
    TextBox,
    Date,
    ComboBox
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ControlType ControlToDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

The value of ControlToDisplay is set in the ViewModel. In the XAML I need to use this Property to display the corresponding control.

Is it possible to do this, and how?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) it might do what you want (sorry don't have time for a full answer, but someone might be able to expand).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546436/

Comment: Do these ViewModel's belong to a list of some sort per chance?

Comment: There actually is a list of objects in the ViewModel and each of these Objects has a ControToDisplay Property.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTemplateSelector` described in [this post](http://ovpwp.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/generic-datatemplateselector/) works very well.