# WPF - how to bind control by MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

i have view:

```
<Grid>
    <!--Some Stuff-->
    <Control XXX="{Binding ButtomControl}"/>
    <!--Some Stuff-->
</Grid>
```

i have VM:

```
public sealed class SelectionDialogV3VM : PropertyChanges
{
    // Some Stuff
    public Control ButtomControl
    {
        get{return _buttomControl;}
        set
        {
            _buttomControl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ButtomControl");
        }
    }
    // Some Stuff
}
```

My objective: in run time change some view (ButtomControl) inside of my main view.
But, i can not do proper binding because i do not know the XXX property.

thanks

Comment: A Control has nothing to do in a ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wanted to add something else:

Referencing a UI control in the view model should be avoided at all cost.

If you want to switch the view via the view model, try using DataTemplates and a ContentControl instead.

See:

http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ButtomControl}"/>
```

But honestly, having a property in your ViewModel of type `Control` is not a good omen :D

Comment: Thanks for answer. Which property was you put in VM? Something, which  realized some interface?

Comment: @zzfima It really depends on what you're trying to do. MVVM is tricky to get right, and it takes time to get used to it.

Comment: Hmm, it's not really tricky. But it takes a lot of discipline to implement it the right way. Just a few rules: 1. Visual elements like Controls, Animations, Colors should only be touched in XAML or code behind. There might be some exceptions, but in most cases it works. 2. Business logic is handled in the ViewModels. 3. The model should be kept as simple as possible and shouldn't contain any business specific logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ContentPresenter:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ButtomControl}"/>
```

Anyway, it's odd to bind to a control!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all, all answers was valuable

Finally, i used DataTriggers, as described here:
[MVVM : how to switch between views using DataTemplate + Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546436/mvvm-how-to-switch-between-views-using-datatemplate-triggers)

Thanks